# How can I show missing text in Netflix movies?

Tags: netflix

The film [Selma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selma_(film)) includes [intertitles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertitle) of FBI surveillance reports that I'm pretty sure are key to the plot.  When streaming Selma on Netflix, the FBI logo is present, but the text of the intertitle is not.  Here is an example from 20:00 of the movie:

[image]

Why are the intertitles missing?  How do I watch Selma with the intertitles on Netflix?

(This problem occurs on Apple TV, on netflix.com using Chrome, and the Windows Store Netflix app.)